# How to check if message contains emojis discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I need to check if a message sent by user contains emojis because my database can't store this type of data. So I thought that I'll use a `message.content.match()` or `message.content.includes()` but when I use it, it still is not enough. I was thinking about making something like blacklist but for emojis and then I realized that I need to save a blacklist of all emojis so I gave up on that. My question for you is, do you know any easier way to make this? I was searching for solution to my problem but I didn't find anything.
Thank you a lot for any help.

````js
if(message.author.id!='botid' && message.author.id===userdbId && message.content.match(/<a?:.+?:\d+>/)){
    const name = args.join(" "); 
    const username = name.slice(0);
    conn.query(`UPDATE users SET ignick='`+username+`' WHERE userID='${message.author.id}'`);
    console.log(username);
    message.channel.send("success message"); 
    conn.end(err => {
        if(err){
        throw error;
        }
        console.log('Disconnected from database');
       })
}
else{
console.log('bot has been stopped from adding his message to database');

}```
At top of this code i made a connect function and two constructors to pull from database userId
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Whenever an emote is used in a message, it follows this format: <:OmegaStonks:723370807308582943>, where the name of the emote is "OmegaStonks" and the id links to the link to the image, like so: https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/723370807308582943.png
> Detecting this pattern is pretty easy using regex.
> `<a?:.+?:\d+>`
> which takes any character from the first : to the second : (and I used a ? to make the wildcard . stop as soon as possible). You also can't have colons in emote names, so it won't abruptly stop there.

[Source](https://www.google.ca/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/gteo6t/discordjs_is_there_a_way_to_detect_emojis_in_a/)

Here is how you could do it

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
if(msg.content.match(/<a?:.+?:\d+>/)) return; //or whatever action(s) you want to do
})
```

Comment: Yes i saw this but thats doesn't work for me. I will try to explain this better. So I have a kind of registry form. When user send message he need to sedn something like !register nicknameofuser. And here is the problem when i use regex of  ``<a?:.+?:\d+>`` it's actualy blocking the emojis but with it it block also the nickname of the user. I will try to copy the code and send it in  message :)

Comment: After more searching to solve my problem i found this regex ```!message.content.match(/(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/g)``` and thats conteins all of emojis :D. And your user can type his nickname soo Thank you a lot for help you make my search easier <3